# Element to encrypt/sign not found

Tags: soapui, ws-security

I am running a soapui method to create a signed message body. I get this error

```
org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: General security error(WSEncryptBody/WSSignEnvelope: Element to encrypt/sign not found: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/, Body)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error when I was running to Soap 1.2 nd point. I tried using Soap 1.1 and it worked fine.

For Body signature specify either "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" for SOAP 1.1 or "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" for SOAP 1.2; Encode type "element"

[Reference](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/Is-it-possible-to-create-a-signature-for-the-BinarySecurityToken/td-p/7839)